# What dummy X server should I use with openoffice on debian?

Tags: debian, x11, openoffice.org, batch-processing

I need to run openoffice in batch mode to turn .doc files into pdf, but openoffice won't start because it needs an X server. My linux box doesn't have one.

Is there some dummy blackhole X server around I can use?

I'm using debian etch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could maybe try [xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb)

> In the X Window System, Xvfb or X
>   virtual framebuffer is an X11 server
>   that performs all graphical operations
>   in memory, not showing any screen
>   output. From the point of view of the
>   client, it acts exactly like any other
>   server, serving requests and sending
>   events and errors as appropriate.
>   However, no output is shown. This
>   virtual server does not require the
>   computer it is running on to even have
>   a screen or any input device. Only a
>   network layer is necessary.

Comment: Tried that and kind of worked. I use xvfb-run and I run into a  X11 error: Can't open display: :99 .

Comment: Installing xfont-base removed the error. xvfb wasn't starting properly because of missing fonts.

Comment: `apt install xvfb;Xvfb :1 &;export DISPLAY=:1`